# Finding $P(X + 10/X > 7 )$ where $X$ is uniform

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. with a continuous uniform distribution on
> $[0,10]$. What is $P \left( X + \frac{10}{X} > 7 \right)$?

#### Attempt

We notice that $X+ \frac{10}{X} > 7$ can be rewritten as $X^2 + 10 - 7X > 0$ which is equivalent to $(X-5)(X-2) > 0$. Thus,

$$ P \left( X + \frac{10}{X} > 7 \right) = P[(X-5)(X-2)>0] = P[ \{X>2 \} \cup \{ X < 5 \} ] $$

Since we have two cases: either $X>5$ and $X>2$ OR $X<5$ and $X<2$. now, using inclusion-exclusion we get

$$ P(X>2) + P(X<5) - P(2<X<5) = 1 - F(2) + F(5) - F(5) + F(2) = 1$$

What is wrong with my solution? According to my solution key, I should get $\frac{7}{10}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: It was a typo. I fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we get
$$P[(X-2)(X-5)>0] = P[\{X<2\}\cup\{X>5\}]=1-P[2<X<5],$$
because the parabola $(x-2)(x-5)$ is positive for $x<2$ and $x>5$. Taking the complement yields the last step. Since $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,10]$, we know $P[2<X<5] = \frac{3}{10}$, so
$$P\left(X+\frac{10}{X}>7\right) = 1-\frac{3}{10} = \frac{7}{10}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note: $\mathsf P(X+\tfrac {10}X>7) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X^2+10>7X)\\ =~ \mathsf P((X-5)(X-2)>0) \\=~ \mathsf P(X<2~\cup~5<X)}$

Plot [$~y=(x-5)(x-2)~$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D(x-5)(x-2)) and look at where it is above the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in $$P[(X-5)(X-2)>0]=P(\{X>2\} \cup \{X<5\})$$ This equality is not correct. Instead $$P[(X-5)(X-2)>0]=P(\{X>5\} \cup \{X<2\})$$